# How can I fetch specific nodes from XML using XPath in Java?

Tags: java, android, xml, xpath, saxparser

My xml file structure is like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<book>
    <chapters>
        <chapter id="1">
            <page id="1" cid= "1" bid = "Book1">
                <text>Hi</text>
            </page>
            <page id="2" cid= "1" bid = "Book1">
                <text>Hi</text>
            </page>
        </chapter>
        <chapter id="2">
            <page id="1" cid= "2" bid = "Book1">
                <text>Hi</text>
            </page>
            <page id="2" cid= "2" bid = "Book1">
                <text>Hi</text>
            </page>
        </chapter>
        <chapter id="3">
            <page id="1" cid= "3" bid = "Book1">
                <text>Hi</text>
            </page>
            <page id="2" cid= "3" bid = "Book1">
                <text>Hi</text>
            </page>
        </chapter>
    </chapters>
</book>
```

I want to get the specific page node by passing **page id**, and **chapter id**. How can I achieve this ?

Also, the book node contains too many chapter and each chapter contains many pages. So, I am using SAX parser to parse the content.

Comment: No xpath support in SAX? : [Can SAX Parsers use XPath in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8791600/can-sax-parsers-use-xpath-in-java)

Comment: I don't believe you can query using xpath with SAX because the document isn't fully held in memory at any time. You can of course store a list of chapters and pages in some data structure while parsing. Can you post your SAX related code?

Comment: @har07 Thanks for your update. I will use DOM Parser. Could you please provide me solution using DOM ?

Comment: @ug_ Thanks for your update. I will use DOM Parser. Could you please provide me solution using DOM ?

Comment: Thanks for your update @Krish

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "How can I fetch specific nodes from XML using XPath in Java?"

I'm not very familiar with Java and Android, but the xpath to get specific `page` from your XML sample, passing `page id` and `chapter id` should look about like this :

```
//chapter[@id='chapter_id_here']/page[@id='page_id_here']
```

**brief explanation :**

- `//chapter` : find `chapter` element anywhere in the XML...
- `[@id='chapter_id_here']` : ...where `id` attribute value equals specific chapter id
- `/page` : from each of filtered `chapter` elements, find child element `page`...
- `[@id='page_id_here']` : ...where `id` attribute value equals specific page id

You can follow these threads for implementation to execute xpath expression in Java : [How to read XML using XPath in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811001/how-to-read-xml-using-xpath-in-java), and in Android : [Search in XML File with XPath in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5519766/search-in-xml-file-with-xpath-in-android)

Comment: How can I specify multiple filters for page? Is the below format correct ?? 



  //page[@id='2'&&@cid='1'&&bid='Book 1']

Comment: `&&` operator in xpath is `and` : `//page[@id='2' and @cid='1' and @bid='Book 1']`