# Search for XML attribute with another attribute in Android

Tags: java, android, xml

I am currently trying to search a local XML File to retrieve a certain attribute, my search key is also another attribute.

My XML is like this:

```
<JPPlatforms>
  <Platform PlatformTag="2980" PlatformNo="47280">
  </Platform>
<JPPlatforms>
```

I want to search the 1000 or so lines for the PlatformNo 47280 and return the PlatformTag 2980.

How would I implement this in Java for Android? Should I use an XMLPullParser is there something more efficient to find and return one particular value in XML?

Comment: Take a look at XPath and possibly XSLT...

Answer (score 1):

**This is trivial if you can use XPath :**

```
//Platform[@PlatformNo=47280]/@PlatformTag
```

**Explanation :**

- `//Platform` : find `Platform` element, anywhere in the XML document...
- `[@PlatformNo=47280]` : ...where `PlatformNo` attribute value equals `47280`
- `/@PlatformTag` : from such `Platform`, return `PlatformTag` attribute

I haven't used XPath in Android, but it seem possible according to this thread : [Search in XML File with XPath in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5519766/search-in-xml-file-with-xpath-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

Try [XMLReader](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/xml/sax/XMLReader.html).

Here is the examples of usage:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/sax/parsing.html
http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-sax-parser/